# Accessing a Parents Array from child added inside movieClip in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, parent, children

I have a movieClip object(Creature), and inside it, i have hitpoints that I would like to add to Creatures Array HitPoints. The way I would like to do this is to have every Parent that may have hitPoints, to have an array called HitPoints so that I can have each point add it self to the Array, regardless of the parent. IE, a skeleton creature and a goblin creature could use the same type of hitPoint objects inside of their base movieClip and still be accessable.

I have omitted some of the unnecessary parts of this class

```
package Assets.Creatures 
{
import Assets.Points.HitPoint;
import Assets.GameStates.Main;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


public class BaseAI_ extends MovieClip 
{
        //Characteristics
    protected var Health : int = 10;
    protected var SPEED : int = 3;
    protected var Intellect : int = 3;
    protected var Strength : int = 3;
    protected var Dexterity : int = 3;
    protected var AttackRange : int = 70;
    protected var Temperment : String = "Agressive";
    //public var Temperment : String = "Passive";
    //public var Temperment : String = "Defensive";

        //ARRAYS
    public var HitPoints : Array = new Array;


        // AttackTimers
    protected var canAttack : Boolean = false;
    protected var AttackSpeed : int;
    protected var AttackTimer : Timer;
    protected var AbilityCooldownsUP : Boolean = false;
    //protected var ABILITY : Timer;

        //AI STATES
    protected var CURRENT_STATE : int = 0;
    protected static var STATE_IDLE : int = 0;
    protected static var STATE_ENGAGE : int = 1;
    protected static var STATE_ATTACK : int = 2;
    protected static var STATE_FLEE : int = 3;

        //Reference
    protected var Target : MovieClip;

        //Directions
    protected var SlopeY : Number;
    protected var SlopeX : Number;
    protected var EngagePosition : Point;
    protected var RunDirection : Number;

    public function BaseAI_() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Awake);

    }   // constructor code

    private function Awake (e : Event) : void
    {
        AttackSpeed = (5000 / Dexterity);
        AttackTimer = new Timer (AttackSpeed, 0);
        AttackTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, AttackSpeedTimer);
        AttackTimer.start();


        Main.main.EnemyArray_2.push(this);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);  
    }

    public function AddHitPoints (hitPoint : MovieClip) : void
    {
        HitPoints.push(hitPoint);
    }
}
```

and the hitPoint class is

```
package Assets.Points 
{
import Assets.Creatures.BaseAI_;
import Assets.Creatures.Player_;
import Assets.Creatures.Player_Human;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class HitPoint extends MovieClip 
{


    public function HitPoint() 
    {   // constructor code
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Awake);
    }   // constructor code

    private function Awake (e : Event) : void
    {
        trace("HitPoints parent is " + parent);
        parent.AddHitPoints(this);
        //parent.HitPoints.push(this)
        //trace("my parent has " + parent.HitPoints.length);
    }


}
}
```

So in the child class (hitPoints) I am adding the hitPoints directly to the ParentClass BaseAI_ on the stage, I have tried a few different ways to add HitPoints both directly with parent.AddHitPoints(this); and parent.HitPoints.push(this)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this.parent and not just parent.

Comment: unfortunately not, also, this.parent would be redundant. Thanks for trying to help though